# Find & Replace in multiple text files within a folder

Tags: batch-file, sublimetext2

I wonder if anyone can help.

I have a large number of text files which have the same type of information. Below are two examples, all the files contain 4 lines:

```
no: 734
word=achieving
def:
LinkToAnother=achieving

no: 657
word=accumulating
def:
LinkToAnother=accumulating
```

[image: Original state of the text within the files]

How can I use Search & Replace (using Regex) in multiple files using Sublime or as an alternative a dos batch file script? It should replace the last three letters of the forth line (`ing`) with the letter (`e`) and therefore achieve the following:

```
no: 734
word=achieving
def:
LinkToAnother=achieve

no: 657
word=accumulating
def:
LinkToAnother=accumulate
```

[image: The outcome of the text within the files]

I am having a headache trying to work out how to only select the second instance of the characters I want within a text file. Very thankful for any help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for %%a in (*.txt) do (
   (for /L %%i in (1,1,4) do set /P "line[%%i]=") < "%%a"
   (for /L %%i in (1,1,3) do echo !line[%%i]!
    echo !line[4]:~0,-3!e) > "%%a"
)
```

That is: "replace the last three letters of the fourth line with the letter (e)".

If this soultion is too slow, there are several modifications that could help to speed it up.

Comment: Hi Aacini, thank you, this works. But how can this be adapted so that it only performs the task on those lines that end with a specific last three characters ("ing") and not any last three characters.  Therefore I can adapt it for other scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

If you install sed via MSYS or WINSED you can do the following

```
sed -b -i -e "4s/ing\(\s*\)$/e\1/"
```

It opens all `*.txt` files (current directory) and edits the 4th line to replace files ending with `ing` and change to `e`.

The carriage return (`\r`) chars are preserved.

Answer (score 0):

Since you were asking how to do this in Sublime Text, the following RegEx pattern works for me in the Find dialog:

**Find:** `^((?:word|LinkToAnother).*)(ing)$`

**Replace:** `$1`

If you want to ignore the key-names, use `^(.*)(ing)$` instead.

**Breakdown**:

- `^` - Start of string, or start of line in multi-line pattern
- first capturing group (will be `$1`):

  - `(?:...)` - Passive (non-c­apt­uring) group for `word` or `LinkToAnother`
  - `.*`- 0 or more of any character (except new line)
- `(ing)` - second capturing group for `ing` (will be `$2`)
- `$` - End of string, or end of line in multi-line pattern

Since we're only after the first capturing group, `$1` is put into the *Replace* field

Comment: Wow, thank you idleberg this works, which book or website page would have taught me this level of regx? Can you explain this in more detail as to what is happening here?

Comment: I'm always going back to the [RegEx Cheat Sheet](https://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/) and I test my patterns on websites such as [RegExr](http://regexr.com/). By the way, please accept the answer if it helped solving your problem!